# 'iif' condition is not working with Calculated Field in SSRS

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, expression, calculated-field

For a dataset in SSRS reports, I've created a calculated field with below expression and it works fine.

`=(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*Fields!Factor.Value`

But sometime we can have factor value as 0. So, I modified above expression with below:

`=iif(Fields!Factor.Value = 0,(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*1,(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*Fields!Factor.Value)`

But this throws below exception: 
*The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.*

Can someone please help to get resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this... `=(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)* IIF(Fields!Factor.Value=0,1,Fields!Factor.Value)` it might give you the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an issue with the IIF, but the datatypes seem to be mismatched.  I have a few suggestions to try.  First, you could try to multiply the true value by 1.0 as I assume the datatypes are decimal or double.  The other option would be to use something like `CInt` to covert the value to the correct datatype.  `CInt` would likely be inappropriate for decimals as it would round off any decimal values, but the idea is the same.  Since your expression doesn't use any aggregates and only uses normal operators, it must relate to something other than the `IIF`.

[Here's a useful link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/data-types-in-expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) to break down the datatypes and conversion methods.  Choose the most appropriate conversion and apply it to the `1`.

EDIT: The expression should be the following.

```
=iif(Fields!Factor.Value = 0.00,
(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*CDbl(1),
(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*Fields!Factor.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you Steve for your suggestions. Based on your recommendations I modified the conditions with below and still same error:

=iif(Convert.ToDouble(Fields!Factor.Value) = 0.00,(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*1,(Fields!SalesAmount.Value+Fields!TaxAmt.Value)*Convert.ToDouble(Fields!Factor.Value))

Comment: @MohsinA. Modified my answer to include an expression I believe should work.

Comment: Steve, I got my problem resolved by below modified expression:

`=iif(len(Fields!Factor.Value) = 0,(convert.ToDouble(Fields!SalesAmount.Value) + convert.ToDouble(Fields!TaxAmt.Value))*1,(convert.ToDouble(Fields!SalesAmount.Value) + convert.ToDouble(Fields!TaxAmt.Value) )*convert.ToDouble(Fields!Factor.Value))`

Comment: @MohsinA. Glad to hear your problem is resolved.  I'd add that you can shorten the `convert.ToDouble` to `CDbl` if you'd prefer to save some space.

Comment: is there any difference between `convert.ToDouble()` and `CDbl()`?

Comment: @MohsinA. Not that I know of.  Both should do the same thing. Convert is a class in the .Net framework library whereas the functions such as CDbl are part of the Visual Basic language.